# How to let NetworkManager manage WLAN interface after upgrade?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, network-manager, console-kit

I upgraded a Ubuntu system from 11.04 to 11.10 via `do-release-uprade`.

Now some things does not work as before.

For example now, my user needs to be part of the `scanner` group to be able to use `xsane` etc. - with `< 11.10` this apparently was not necessary.

To be able to use `nm-applet` again (for wired networking) I needed to add the user to the group `netdev` after the upgrade.

But WLAN management still does not work via NetworkManager - `nm-applet` just does not display any wireless devices.

In the logs there is:

```
NetworkManager wlan0 deactivating device reason managed
```

(inter-punctuation removed)

But why it is suddenly managed?

I checked `/etc/network/interfaces` and it does not contain any `wlan0` entries.

And `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` just contains:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Is there some other group the user needs to be part of? Or what else could be messed up after an upgrade?

Manually connecting to a WLAN-AP via wpasupplicant and dhclient (after stopping NetworkManager) works perfectly fine.

**Edit:** Btw, this Ubuntu system is a little bit non-standard:

- `wdm` is configured as display manger instead of `lightdm`
- as window manager I use `awesomewm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ***backup*** before you use the commands below, I don't know if you will have internet afterwards.

Connect using ethernet cable.

1. Download the packages so you have a way to reinstall them even without internet:

   ```
   cd
   apt-get download network-manager-gnome network-manager
   ```
2. Then I'd suggest to purge your network manager configuration:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
   sudo rm -rf /etc/NetworkManager
   sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/NetworkManager
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/NetworkManager
   ```
3. And reinstall network manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager
   ```

   If you don't have internet anymore try installing the local packages we downloaded with the first command:

   ```
   cd
   sudo dpkg -i network-manager*.deb
   ```
4. Restart the computer.

If the above commands did not fix the internet, we need more info:

1. Run these commands and provide the output (edit your question):

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   cat /etc/network/interfaces
   iwconfig
   ifconfig
   lspci -nn
   lsusb
   nm-tool
   sudo lshw -C network
   rfkill list all
   ```
2. Check that you have all the dependencies installed correctly, reinstall the ubuntu meta-packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P --force-all ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal
   ```
3. You never mentioned which Ubuntu version you used before you upgraded to 11.10.

Note: By the way, AFAIK the `do-release-uprade` command should be used when upgrading ***server*** installations, not desktop. You should prefer downloading the alternate cd of the through update-manager.

Comment: Nice write up - I will try it after a proper backup - I upgraded from the previous version (i.e. Natty, which is 11.04)

Comment: Ok, removing those NM directories and reinstalling did not help, looked at the output of nm-applet and there seems to be a dbus permission problem: `_nm_object_get_property: Error getting 'ActiveConnections' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: (9) Rejected send message` - I'll post a new question for this

Comment: See also my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The log message

```
NetworkManager wlan0 deactivating device reason managed
```

sent me on a wrong route. Managed or unmanaged devices are not the problem.

Another thing that can go wrong (besides not being part of the right group or managed device issues) is a DBus permission problem.

One can check this via starting `nm-applet` from a xterm, in case there is a permission problem you get a lot of `Rejected send message`s like this:

```
$ nm-applet
** (nm-applet:25178): WARNING **: _nm_object_get_property: Error getting 'WirelessHardwareEnabled' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: (9) Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1698" (uid=SOMEUID pid=SOMEPID comm="nm-applet ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=OTHERPID comm="NetworkManager ")
```

Well, `nm-applet` seems to be really great at reporting such errors to the user ... via it'ts GUI ... NOT!

(Ok, `nm-applet` also fails to report that a user is not part of the `netdev` group ...)

It seems to have something to do with [ConsoleKit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConsoleKit). It seems that `nm-applet` needs an ConsoleKit-Session that has `active = TRUE`.

You can check your ConsoleKit-session via:

```
$ ck-list-sessions
```

On my system the output was:

```
$ ck-list-sessions | grep active
    active = FALSE
    active = FALSE
    active = FALSE
```

To test if this really the problem you can call `nm-applet` like this from a xterm:

```
$ ck-launch-session nm-applet
```

Then you should not get `Rejected send` 'Warning' messages any more and `nm-applet` should work as expected.

This workaround probably breaks other ConsoleKit related stuff - the real fix probably would be to fix ConsoleKit-session-setup via the display manager or something like that.

Note that `ConsoleKit` is also [kind of unmaintained](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit) and is probably replaced in the near future by a Systemd based solution ...

**Edit:** See also my answer to a related [console kit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35603/1131) setup problem. Depending on your X11 startup method you need to workaround ConsoleKit changes such that you get an active session - depending on your ConsoleKit version and system just calling `ck-launch-session` might not be enough.